MySQL trigger on update set new value to old value from another column
I have code:
CREATE TRIGGER update_after_requirement_on_description
BEFORE UPDATE
ON requirement FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF !(NEW.description <=> OLD.description) THEN
        UPDATE requirement
        SET NEW.description_previous = OLD.description;
    END IF;
END;

and second one:
CREATE TRIGGER update_after_requirement_on_description
BEFORE UPDATE
ON requirement FOR EACH ROW
IF !(NEW.description <=> OLD.description) THEN
    UPDATE requirement
    SET NEW.description_previous = OLD.description;
END IF;

both return result from db:
#1064 - Something is wrong in your syntax near '' in line:
"SET NEW.description_previous = OLD.description;"
what's wrong ?
thanks
EDIT:
this version works:
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER update_after_requirement_on_description
BEFORE UPDATE
ON requirement FOR EACH ROW
    IF !(NEW.description <=> OLD.description) THEN
        SET NEW.description_previous = OLD.description;
    END IF;
$$
DELIMITER ;


The error message tells that you forget about DELIMITER.

@Akina thanks it hepled (but previes i created few another triggers and i didnt need DELIMITER)

Simply
CREATE TRIGGER update_after_requirement_on_description 
BEFORE UPDATE ON requirement 
FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.description_previous = CASE WHEN !(NEW.description <=> OLD.description) 
                                    THEN OLD.description 
                                    ELSE NEW.description_previous 
                                    END;

And you do not need in DELIMITER.

why « UPDATE requirement» before set ?
just use set :
CREATE TRIGGER update_after_requirement_on_description
BEFORE UPDATE
ON requirement FOR EACH ROW
IF !(NEW.description <=> OLD.description) THEN
    SET NEW.description_previous = OLD.description;
END IF;


Also i tried your version previes and when i execute this version i have the same error: #1064 - Something is wrong in your syntax near '' in line 5 - so i tried few versions and i have problem with this :/

this version works:
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER update_after_requirement_on_description
BEFORE UPDATE
ON requirement FOR EACH ROW
    IF !(NEW.description <=> OLD.description) THEN
        SET NEW.description_previous = OLD.description;
    END IF;
$$

DELIMITER;

by @Akina
